# Wordpress edit post - move Categories box to left column

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, when you edit a post categories are displayed on the right column (assuming a 2-column layout)...

[image: default layout]

How do you move this to the left column, right below the content editor?

[image: desired layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your mouse over top of the `Categories` box title, and you should get the `move` icon. Then just drag the box where you want it in the left column.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the category section box to the left where the content box (right below it)

Comment: Many thanks. *sigh* I only wish this was the dumbest thing I've asked on Stackoverflow...